# How to search for more than one item with .filter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I make it so i can search for more than one item. Right now I have it so it can only search for name, and I want to be able to search for id and name.

I've tried multiple solutions for example this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter without success.

CODE:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [masterDataSource] = useState(DataBase);

  const filteredDataSource = masterDataSource.filter((item) => {
    return item.name.includes(search);
  });

return(
<TextInput
   onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
   value={search}
 />
)
```

.

DataBase

```
{
    id: '1234567788900',
    name: 'AWD',
    company: 'HALDEX',
  },
```

Comment: `item.name.includes(search) || item.id.includes(search)`

Comment: use `lodash` package. It's awesome and solve your problem easily.

Comment: @VLAZ already tried this. When trying to type something it throws an error that includes is undefined

Comment: @Lmao12233 if you get an error that `includes` is `undefined`, then your `id` property is not a string. However, [your other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920802/how-to-search-for-more-than-one-item-with-filter?noredirect=1#comment116553087_65920873) says that you're getting `Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined ` which instead means that there is no property called `id`.

Comment: @VLAZ It's fixed now. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @susanta96 [let's not go there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

Comment: Lol. Sorry my bad.(: @VLAZ. I just though if adding package isn't an issue then `lodash` can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simple, just add another condition with `or(||)` operator.

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const [masterDataSource] = useState(DataBase);

const filteredDataSource = masterDataSource.filter((item) => {
  return (item.name.includes(search) || (item.id && item.id.includes(search))) // add the condition in or 
});

return ( 
 <TextInput 
  onChangeText = {text => setSearch(text)}
  value = {search}
 />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is this snippet, you can check mutlpiple properties

```js
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [masterDataSource] = useState(DataBase);

  const filteredDataSource = masterDataSource.filter((item) => {
    return item.name.includes(search) && item.id=== your_id;
  });

return(
<TextInput
   onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
   value={search}
 />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if both properties contain the substring of searched text

```js
const dummyArr = [{
    id: '1234567788900',
    name: 'AWD',
    company: 'HALDEX',
  },
  {
    id: '123456778800',
    name: 'BWD',
    company: 'hello world',
  },
  {
    id: '1234568800',
    name: 'BWDsa',
    company: 'hello world',
  }
]

const searchText = document.querySelector('#search')

searchText.onkeyup = function($el) {
 const filterResult = dummyArr.filter(el => el.id.includes($el.target.value) || el.name.includes($el.target.value) )
 console.log(filterResult)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" />
```